# MATLAB Font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, matlab

I want to write a single command from MATLAB in LaTeX using the MatLab font. I have found a lot of examples using listing, but that is for the whole code.

I only want to change the font for one word, while keeping the text flow.

Comment: What is "the Matlab font"? A monospaced font? If so, just write `\verb+MatlabCommandHere+`.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for! Thank You!